# Script / automator action that combines pdfs with the same name from different folders

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, pdf

I'm trying to write a simple script / automator tool that should achieve the following:
I have 600 Pdf-Files in one folder and 600 Pdf-Files with the identical names in a different folder. Now I would like to combine the matching files with each other, so that I get 600 merged Pdf-files as a result.  Can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. What have you done so far? because this is not a free coding service.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, combining two pdfs into one (there are similar questions with answers already on the site), looping through all files in one folder and finding the matching one in the other folder, or something else?

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I specifically have a problem to get the script to match the correct files. I figured out how to combine two files and save them to the right location but I can’t figure out how to match the correct files. (I‘m an absolute beginner)

Comment: Please add the script (or a screenshot thereof) of what you have so far. It's way easier to propose ways to improve an existing script than to do everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the third-party *command line tool*, `cpdf`, and *script* the process of merging the **PDF** *documents*.

Have a look at: [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools Community Release](http://community.coherentpdf.com/)

- [Download pre-built cpdf tool](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries/archive/master.zip) (This is a direct download link. Building from source is available from link on main page linked above.)
- A comprehensive user manual for the PDF tools can be found as a [PDF document](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf), or [browsable online](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/cpdfmanual.html).
- **Note:** the **Community Release** version of **Coherent PDF Command Line Tools** is **free** fo non-commercial use.

Copy the appropriate `cpdf` *binary executable* from the extracted **cpdf-binaries-master.zip** file to a *directory* that is in the `PATH` passed to the *shell*.

---

### To use the *example* **shell script** *code*:

In **Terminal**, run the following *compound command*:

```
f="mergepdf"; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod 0755 "$f"
```

In the opened **mergepdf** *document*, copy and paste the *example* **shell script** *code*, shown below, into the *document*, and then save and close the *document*.

- <sup>**Note:** If you did don't copy the `cpdf` *binary executable* to a *directory* that is in the `PATH` passed to the *shell*, then use the *fully qualified pathname* of the `cpdf` *binary executable* in the *shell script*.</sup>

Back in **Terminal**:

```
./mergepdf
```

Outputs:

```
Parameter missing!...
Example: mergepdf '/path/to/PDF Files 1' '/path/to/PDF Files 2' '/path/to/Merged PDF Files'
```

- <sup>**Note:** I'd move the `mergepdf` *file* to a location that's within the `PATH` passed to *shell scripts*, then you'd not have to preface the *command* with `./`, or include it's *fully qualified pathname*.</sup>

---

### *Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "${3}" ]; then
    echo "Parameter missing!..."
    echo "Example: mergepdf '/path/to/PDF Files 1' '/path/to/PDF Files 2' '/path/to/Merged PDF Files'"
    exit 1
fi  

oridir="${1}"
dupdir="${2}"
merdir="${3}"

if [ ! -d  "${oridir}" ]; then
    echo "The directory \"${oridir}\" does not exist!..."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d  "${dupdir}" ]; then
    echo "The directory \"${dupdir}\" does not exist!..."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d  "${merdir}" ]; then
    echo "The directory \"${merdir}\" does not exist!..."
    exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r orifile; do

    while IFS= read -r dupfile; do

        if [ -e "${dupfile}" ]; then
            if [ ! -e "${merdir}/${orifile##*/}" ]; then
                cpdf "${orifile}" "${dupfile}" -o "${merdir}/${orifile##*/}" 2>/dev/null
            else
                echo "\"${orifile##*/}\" already exists in \"${merdir}\"."
            fi
        else
            echo "No match found for \"${orifile}\" in \"${dupdir}/\"."
        fi

    done <<< "$(find "${dupdir}" -type f -name "${orifile##*/}")"

done < <(find "${oridir}" -type f -iname '*.pdf')
```

---

### What the *shell script* does:

Finds of all *files* with a **pdf** *extension* in `'/path/to/PDF Files 1'` and then attempts to find the *file* of the same *name* in `'/path/to/PDF Files 2'`.

If it finds the *file* of the same *name* in `'/path/to/PDF Files 2'` it *merges* the two *files* with a **pdf** *extension* having the same *name* to `'/path/to/Merged PDF Files'`, *merging* the second *file* to the end of the first *file*. Note that other *command line options* for the `cpdf` *binary executable* are available.

If a *duplicate* **.pfd** *document* of the same *name* is not found in `'/path/to/PDF Files 2'`, then a message it output.

As coded, existing *files* in `'/path/to/Merged PDF Files'` are not overwritten. If a *file* exists a message is output.

---

**Notes:**

Because the `cpdf` *binary executable* is not *signed*, you'll have to allow it to run by clicking the **[Allow Anyway]** button in: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **General**

The *example* **shell script** *code*, shown above, was tested as an *executable shell script* in **Terminal** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

Testing under **macOS Big Sur** 11.4, I did not have any issue with the `cpdf` *binary executable* concerning its *signing* and it simply worked by copying the **OSX-Intel** version of `cpdf` to a location that's within the `PATH` passed to *shell scripts*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **shell script** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>